# Passing and using struct with typedef

Tags: c, struct, typedef

how can i use the next struct with typedef by passing it to another function like that?

I have tried this code but i doesn't seem to be working.

```
typedef struct stru{
    int num;
} stru;

int main(void)
{
    stru current;
    struc(&current);
    printf("%d", current.num);
}


int struc(stru* current)
{
    *current.num = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

It didn't worked because its not the right way to set it to 1 i guess can someone help me to do it , i have tried few other ways but neither of them is working

```
*current.num = 1;
```

Comment: @SLaks well its not workint to set *current.num = 1; by that way

Comment: `current->num = 1;` postfix has higher precedence than unary.

Comment: What happens? What error do you get?

Comment: @SLaks Error: exprassion must have struct or union type

Answer (score 2):

Unary `*` has less precedence than `.`.

Therefore, your code is parsed as `*(current.num) = 1`, which is very much not what you want.

Instead, you need to force the dereference to happen first: `(*current).num`.

This is so common that C has a shorthand for it: `current->num`.

Comment: Oops; the `*` should have been inside the parentheses.